# R: Extracting the mean of a column from an imported dataset, while discounting one value

Tags: r, mean

I'm trying to find the mean of a column called GDP within a dataset called WDI. I've tried using `mean(WDI$GDP)` but I think it's not working because some of the values are "..". I'm not able to change these values in the dataset; is there any way to get the mean while excluding the ".." values?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `..` means it is a `character` vector.  One option is to wrap with `as.numeric` so that all the character elements are converted to `NA`, and then use `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean`

```
mean(as.numeric(WDI$GDP), na.rm = TRUE)
```

NOTE: This will also show a friendly warning in the console

```
as.numeric(c(1, "..", 2))
[1]  1 NA  2
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

If those warning messages are not okay, then another option is to remove those elements, before converting to `numeric`

```
with(WDI, mean(as.numeric(WDI[WDI != ".."])))
```